# nodejs express application won't return json array

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I have the following express node.js app. It's using the 'redis' npm package.

```
app.get("/test",function(req,res){
    var data = [];
    client.HGETALL("receipts",function(err,obj){
        for(var id in obj){
            data.push(JSON.parse(obj[id]));
        }
    });
    console.log(data);
    res.json(data);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The code run's without errors; however, the `data` variable is `[]` when it's returned to the browser.
[image: browser]

The strange part is that when I run the same redis commands from the command line, the array is populated.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is asynchronous. The callback you pass doesn't get executed until *after* your `console.log`. Try:

```
app.get("/test",function(req,res){
    var data = [];
    client.HGETALL("receipts",function(err,obj){
        for(var id in obj){
            data.push(JSON.parse(obj[id]));
        }
        console.log(data);
        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Doh! I figured it was something like that. Originally i was just doing `res.send(data)` and i tried putting it inside the callback. But since that was wrong too i didn't see that was the solution. thank you!

Comment: @MattPhillips, that first method should've worked just fine!?

Comment: so you can do res.send and pass json and it will set the headers properly? I swear it wasn't working.

Comment: @MattPhillips, depends what you mean by "properly". You can set the headers either way, although presumably (need to check) `.send()` uses text/html and `.json()` uses json headers. How important that is depends on your use case I suppose.

Comment: well when the url i'm "GET"-ing in the client code expects application/json. So I'd say pretty important. That way I don't have to parse it back out on the client side.

Comment: Fair enough, then `.json()` seems like the more natural fit. Either way you can only execute them at the end of the callback. Take care.